# DataTable GroupBy and check condition

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable that is populated like shown below. The datatable typically contains multiple of the same 'UnitNr'.

When I group the datatable, I'm trying to achieve a behavior that checks if a specific 'event' has taken place on that specific 'UnitNr'. E.g. (So it will filter out 'UnitNr' where the event is = "1st Installment")

When the datatable is filtered from any unwanted data, the data should go to a new datatable that will be bound to a gridview.

```
public static void GetNextPayments(RadGridView Grid)
{
    DataTable dt;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Varribles.ConString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT Date, ClientID, Event, FirstInstallment, SecondInstallment, UnitNr, FirstInstallmentPayDate, SecondInstallmentPayDate FROM Customers WHERE Approved = 'Approved';";
        using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            adapter.Dispose();
        }
        con.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
    test(dt);
}
```

Now I group the datatable like shown below.

**UPDATE - Below has been modified**

The code below still returns values where 1st installment. Witch it should not

```
 private static void test(DataTable dt)
    {
        var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("UnitNr"))
.Where(grp => grp.Any(x => x.Field<string>("Event") != "1st installment" && x.Field<string>("Event") == "Deposit"));

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Key);

        }
    }
```

Comment: So consider adding `.Where(rg => !rg.Any(r => r.Field<string>("Event") != skipEvent))`.